# Past participle of haben

Tags: participle

To ask someone if they had fun, I could say:

> Hast du Spaß gehabt?

But why is it `gehabt`, and not `gehaben`? How is the participle formed?

Would I still ask it formally using `gehabt`?, i.e.

> Haben Sie Spaß gehabt?

I thought the participle might have been conjugated like the verb is, i.e. 'gehaben' with 'Sie' and 'gehast' with 'Du', but maybe not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's *gehabt*, because *[haben](http://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/haben.htm)* is a weak verb, not a strong one.

The [past participle](http://www.vistawide.com/german/grammar/german_verbs.htm) for weak verbs is formed by:

> ge + infinitive stem + (e)t

like machen - gemacht, haben - gehabt, kaufen - gekauft, blenden - geblendet

For strong verbs it's:

> ge + perfect stem + en

like singen - gesungen, fahren - gefahren, trinken - getrunken

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the verb foms, the participle does not follow the *person* (there is no gehaben and no gehast). Think of it more like an adjective, which can follow *case*, *number* and *genus*. It is formed with suffix -t or -en, depending on whether it is a weak or strong verb, and with prefix ge- (unless the verb itself has a prefix already, thus it is 'Ich habe mich verlaufen' and not 'geverlaufen' or 'vergelaufen'; then again it is 'Ich bin weggelaufen', sigh).

Comment: "Weg-" is a separable prefix. That's why it's different than "ver-".